# Compare two JSON object and find missing values using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have two JSON objects `counties`, and `ctyIndem`. The `counties` object has all the counties in a US State, and `ctyIndem` has the indemnities paid in that State by county, but not those counties which no payment has been made. What I need to do is to iterate through both JSON, and if a county is missing from `ctyIndem` add the missing info from `counties`.

JS

```
var counties = [{
    FIPS: 1001,
    County: "Autauga",
    State: "ALABAMA"
    }, {
    FIPS: 1003,
    County: "Baldwin",
    State: "ALABAMA"
    }, {
   FIPS: 1005,
   County: "Barbour",
   State: "ALABAMA"
   }, {
   FIPS: 1007,
   County: "Bibb",
   State: "ALABAMA"
   }, {
   FIPS: 1009,
   County: "Blount",
   State: "ALABAMA"
   }, {
   FIPS: 1011,
  County: "Bullock",
  State: "ALABAMA"
  }];

  var ctyIndem = [{
  Year: 2015,
  State: "ALABAMA",
  id: 1001,
  County: "Autauga",
  Indem: 50
  }, {
  Year: 2015,
  State: "ALABAMA",
  id: 1003,
  County: "Baldwin",
  Indem: 200
  }, {
  Year: 2015,
  State: "ALABAMA",
  id: 1005,
  County: "Barbour ",
  Indem: 1501
  }];


  counties.forEach(function(a, v) {

  if (a.FIPS == ctyIndem[v].id) { //County is present, then is ok
    console.log(ctyIndem[v].id); 
   } else {//County not present, add new info

   var temp = [];
       temp.push({
       Year: ctyIndem[0].Year,
       State: a.State,
       id: a.FIPS,
       County: a.County,
       Indem: 0
      });
    Array.prototype.push.apply(ctyIndem, temp);
     }

     });

    console.log(ctyIndem);
```

The issue is when I iterate throught the array and gets to the point when the county FIPS and id don't match, I really not sure what to do there. I keep getting a **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined** error, because obviously there is no match.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems like your logic is all wrong. You're expecting the counties to have the same index in both arrays. You need to search the entire `ctyIndem` array to see if there's one with a matching ID.

Comment: Why are you using `Array.prototype.push.apply`? Just write `ctyIndem.push({ ... })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your searching logic is wrong. It only checks whether the element at the same index in `ctyIndem` has the matching `id`. But the indexes in the two arrays don't match. You need to search the entire array.

A simple way to do this is to create an object whose keys are the IDs you want to search for. Then you can just use `a.FIPS` as an index to see if it exists.

```
var ctyIds = {};
ctyIndem.forEach(function(c) {
    ctyIds[c.id] = true;
});

counties.forEach(function(a) {
    if (!ctyIds[a.FIPS]) {
        ctyIndem.push({
            Year: ctyIndem[0].Year,
            State: a.State,
            id: a.FIPS,
            County: a.County,
            Indem: 0
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you first need to check that `ctyIndem[v]` exists

```
//  v--- check that it exists
if (ctyIndem[v] && a.FIPS == ctyIndem[v].id) { //County is present, then is ok
  console.log(ctyIndem[v].id); 
 } else {//County not present, add new info
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a flat array with just the ids from ctyIndem.  Using the Array.filter method, you can generate an array of counties missing from the list of ids. Then push in a new object for each missing county:

```
    var indemIds = ctyIndem.map(function (c) { return c.id });

    var missingFromIndem = counties.filter(function (cnty) {
      return indemIds.indexOf(cnty.FIPS) === -1;
    });

    missingFromIndem.forEach(function (cnty) {
      ctyIndem.push({
        id: cnty.FIPS,
        State: cnty.State,
        County: cnty.County
      });
    });
```